# NA not showing in ggplot2 scatterplot using qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, na

I am using `qplot` from `ggplot2` to make a scatter plot. I am not able to see all values in the x-axis. Also, it is removing the `NA` from x-axis. How to retain `NA` and control what the number of features shown in x-axis?

```
rate_plot = qplot(Result$temp, Result$CR, main="Rate", xlab=feature, ylab="Rate", size=I(3))+
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

[image: Plot looks like this]

**Data:**
[Google Docs link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqwKO9RfLx7_W5QakTM9Lfn2PPS97mYOVSRKY9_U624/edit?usp=sharing)

```
Result <- read.table(text = "   temp    NCH type    CH  i.type  CR
1   NA  1878464 nochurn 549371  churn   0.226280204
2   1.87    2236    nochurn 4713    churn   0.678227083
3   2.14    4945    nochurn 8530    churn   0.633024119
4   2.25    423 nochurn 972 churn   0.696774194
5   2.79    3238    nochurn 7692    churn   0.703751144
6   3.25    266817  nochurn 12678   churn   0.045360382
7   3.33    2132    nochurn 4295    churn   0.668274467
8   5.1 6683    nochurn 7743    churn   0.536739221
9   6   342554  nochurn 21648   churn   0.059439542
10  6.51    1785    nochurn 4764    churn   0.727439304
11  8   13668   nochurn 22751   churn   0.624701392
12  9.85    6005    nochurn 14687   churn   0.709791224
13  11.99   378 nochurn 850 churn   0.69218241", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: What do you mean "not able to see all values in the x-axis"? Maybe see [scale_x_continuous](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/scale_continuous.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I can now add more labels to my x-axis. That solves one of the problems.

Comment: What problem doesn't it solve?

Comment: How do you want to show NA on xaxis?

Comment: @Gregor `NA` values are still not shown.
@zx8754 Separately, towards the end of x-axis. But I definitely want to show them and not remove them from the plot

Comment: I am also getting this warning `Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).` which may be the reason I am not seeing it.

Comment: Update dataframe for NA values, change the x to max(x) + 1, and when using scale_x_continous we can supply breaks and labels, so the last label would be "NA".

Comment: Dataframe already has `NA` as shown in the data shown in the google sheet. I don't want to supply labels as it is already present in the dataframe. I will experiment with your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting the `na.value` argument of `scale_x_continuous()`? Maybe setting it to wherever you want the missing values to be displayed?

Comment: @Gregor heh, first time I see that argument :) Do you mind if I add to my solution?

Comment: @Gregor I tried that but it doesn't affect anything. Setting it as `TRUE` or `FALSE` is just shifting the points by a small margin and not adding/removing any extra point. Although I think point corresponding to `NA` is present , but only the label for `NA` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom ticks and labels we can use [scale_x_continuous](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/scale_continuous.html).

Below warning means rows with NA values are dropped from plot data:

> Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point)

Workaround to make NA show up on x-axis, we need to assign some value for NA values, here I am plotting NA values on right end of the plot. Get the max value for xaxis (`temp` variable) then use custom x axis label.

```
library(ggplot2)

# set NA to max value + 1
plotDat <- Result
plotDat[ is.na(plotDat$temp), "temp"] <- max(ceiling(plotDat$temp), na.rm = TRUE) + 1

#plot with custom breaks and labels
ggplot(plotDat, aes(x = temp, y = CR)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:max(ceiling(plotDat$temp)),
                     labels = c(1:(max(ceiling(plotDat$temp)) - 1), "NA"))
```

[image]

Comment: While this would work, my actual code generates plots for 500+ features with hugely varying x-axis ranges which `ggplot2` is able to take care of and show labels accordingly. If I put the range `1:n`, it would always fill in all labels and would become very cluttered for some ranges.

`scale_x_continuous(na.value = TRUE)` is keeping the NA value, only not showing it in the x-axis.

Comment: @Shivendra `na.value` argument requires a number. When we set it to `TRUE` it gets converted to `1` and is getting plotted.

Comment: Oh yes, I see the problem here. I want a non-number to be shown on a scale which is continuous.
For some of the features `NA` values were showing up. This means `ggplot2` treated them as `factor` while in this case, it is treating them as `continuous` and thus I am facing the difficulty.

Comment: I think I am going to use the method suggested by you, till I find a better solution. I will bucket in order to accommodate labels and I will use the 'regular' way for features with `temp` column as `character/factor`.